# RestTemplate postForEntity experiencing java.io.IOException: Premature EOF error

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

Would appreciate any help regarding my issue on one of my maven projects.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://test-services.domain.ph/campaign/": Premature EOF; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:666)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:407)
at homecredit.ph.CampaignConnector.call(CampaignConnector.java:46)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAheadBlocking(ChunkedInputStream.java:565)
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAhead(ChunkedInputStream.java:609)
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:696)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
```

Origin:

```
ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity, ApiResponse.class);
```

Destination:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/campaign", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> insertCampaignRecord(
        @Valid @RequestBody CampaignRecordInsertRequest campaignRecordInsertRequest){
    logInfo("Incoming insert request. " + DescriptorUtility.convertToString(campaignRecordInsertRequest));
    campaignDataService.insertNewRecord(CampaignRecordConverter.convertToCampaignRecord(campaignRecordInsertRequest));
    return ResponseUtility.defaultResponse();
}
```

ResponseUtility

```
public static ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> defaultResponse(){
    ApiResponse apiResponse = new ApiResponse();
    apiResponse.setTimestamp(DateUtility.currentDateString());
    apiResponse.setMessage(ResponseMessages.SUCCESS);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(apiResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

CampaignData Service

```
@Async("AsyncExecutor")
public void insertNewRecord(CampaignRecord campaignRecord) {
    try {
        campaignRecordRepository.save(campaignRecord);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logError(e);
    }
}
```

Server Log

```
2017-09-11 11:11:11  INFO 18383 [http-nio-8773-exec-10] [CampaignRecordController] - Incoming insert request. {"dateCampaign":1504656000000,"cuid":...
2017-09-11 11:11:11  WARN 18383 [http-nio-8773-exec-10] [SqlExceptionHelper] - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
2017-09-11 11:11:11 ERROR 18383 [http-nio-8773-exec-10] [SqlExceptionHelper] - Duplicate entry 'CMP_CLX##1208637#20170906' for key 'UNIQUE_KEY'
2017-09-11 11:11:11 ERROR 18383 [http-nio-8773-exec-10] [CampaignDataService] - could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
2017-09-11 11:11:11 ERROR 18383 [http-nio-8773-exec-10] [CampaignDataService] - could not execute statement
```

PS. Server logs is normal(return a successful response either record successfully saved or not)

Issue is intermittent. Occurs randomly when sending bulk requests.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: These are client logs, any traces you see in server logs?

Comment: Updated problem description with logs.
But server is async designed so either failed or not, it must return a successful response.

Comment: Share campaignDataService.insertNewRecord code too.

Comment: added campaignDataService.insertNewRecord code.
Already tried removing asynchronous implementation, still issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Spring Boot 2.1. In my case I had 3 apps (call them A, B, and C) where B was really just a proxy between A and C:

```
A --> B --> C
```

The `Premature EOF` was occurring on the response *from* B *to* A. All indications were a successful HTTP response (200), but inspecting the body of the response using a debugger revealed it had a new line character in the *middle* of the serialized DTO data, instead of at the end where I expected it:

[image]

(Notice the return character after the `id` field, and lack of any content length; ignore the unreadable boxes at the end, they're part of the byte array that are not initialized/used)

In my case, Service B is both a server and a client. The code looked something like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> handle(String request, HttpHeaders headers) {

    // Do some validation and then call Service C, and pass the response
    // back to Service A

    return restTemplate.postForEntity(
        urlForServiceC,
        new HttpEntity<>(request, headers),
        String.class);
}
```

I didn't dive too far into the guts of `RestTemplate` or its message converters, but what tipped me off that there might be an issue with the response buffering is that I was using a [Spring filter](https://gist.github.com/michael-pratt/89eb8800be8ad47e79fe9edab8945c69) to log the responses of each service. This filter has to copy the response stream to avoid exceptions from other filters related to the body already being consumed.

What I noticed is that when I ran with this filter *enabled*, the `Premature EOF` exceptions went away. And when I *disabled* it, the exceptions came back. Something about copying the response stream had solved the `Premature EOF` errors.

This led me to try the following in Service B:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> handle(String request, HttpHeaders headers) {

    // Do some validation and then call Service C, and pass the response
    // back to Service A

    String response = restTemplate.postForEntity(
        urlForServiceC,
        new HttpEntity<>(request, headers),
        String.class).getBody();

    return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
}
```

The subtle change is that I'm saving the response first to a local variable, which requires me to call `ResponseEntity.getBody()`. This forces the entire response body from Service C to be consumed before returning to Service A. After making this change my `Premature EOF` errors have not returned.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the server logs seems like, the server is trying save some record and its failing (due to Unique key violation).

```
2017-09-11 11:11:11  WARN 18383 [http-nio-8773-exec-10] [SqlExceptionHelper] - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
2017-09-11 11:11:11 ERROR 18383 [http-nio-8773-exec-10] [SqlExceptionHelper] - Duplicate entry 'CMP_CLX##1208637#20170906' for key 'UNIQUE_KEY'
2017-09-11 11:11:11 ERROR 18383 [http-nio-8773-exec-10] [CampaignDataService] - could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
2017-09-11 11:11:11 ERROR 18383 [http-nio-8773-exec-10] [CampaignDataService] - could not execute statement
```

Looks like the server is not able to handle the exception gracefully and the whole flow breaks, causing a HTTP-500 response code (probably) with an empty response.

Two actions you can take:

1. Handle the exception gracefully.
2. Verify why unique key is getting violated and fix that if possible.

Comment: Hi, as shown on my controller, whatever the result after data insertion, I'm returning a FIXED response so I don't think this is the issue :)

Comment: Code is wrapped under try-catch so exception is not going to propagate. Next step would be to log the response in String format don't try to wrap it under ApiResponse in single step, this would help you to identify what are you receiving from server. Also why are you making the service method as @Async, if you are on Servlet 3.1 use Async controllers (e.g. Callable or DeferredResult)

Comment: Upvote for making me realize to check with ResponseEntity. 
Although issue seems to be unrelated, anyway, Thanks!

My bad for not pointing it out earlier.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might be experiencing this.
Issue was caused by spring boot eureka.
Seems like there is a bug when it comes to passing ResponseEntity response in a massive scale (bulk processing) that causes the response status to be malformed.

Current workaround is to switch from ResponseEntity to the object body instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when i use RestTemplate with default http client factory.I found it missing 'Accept-Encoding:gzip' in the headers when I capture packets.Finally i get it by replace the default http client factory with apache's http client factory,like this:

```
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClientBuilder.create().build());
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
```